# Java application Performance issue in Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, amazon-eks, java-11

I have a Java Spring boot application (Memory intensive). when I run the standalone jar file on a 1 core and 1 GB RAM Virtual Machine, I can able to get the 1000 TPS without any issue. and when I am deploying the same jar file in Kubernetes both EKS and GKE I can see there is more than 50% performance issue (I am getting 400 TPS max with 1 core and 1 GB ram resource limit configured in deployment yaml).

Kubernetes version: 1.21
Docker Base image: adoptopenjdk 11

Is there anything that we need to configure to achieve the same result as Virtual Machine(Standalone jar)?

Comment: Are you using resource limits? Don't. If you're using a relatively new version of Java (10+) you shouldn't have to set the heap size but it couldn't hurt. See https://oracle.github.io/weblogic-kubernetes-operator/faq/resource-settings/. CPU  sharing is a little wonky on Linux. I recommend reading this blog as background, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/using-prometheus-to-avoid-disasters-with-kubernetes-cpu-limits/. It's best to avoid setting CPU limits especially if CPU is bursty.

Comment: Our application is Memory intensive, If I remove the CPU and memory limits, i still can see more memory usage (by running top command). I need to understand why there is huge difference compared to running jar file on a plain VM and Deployed on Kubernetes as a docker image

Comment: Like I said, you can try setting Xms and Xmx along with other JAVA_OPTS to tune the environment. Might be worth printing those out to see what the defaults are.

Comment: Adding these JAVA OPTS are fine, but my concern is performance issue in the Kubernetes compared to normal deployment (run jar file on a server)

Normal Deployment with 1 core and 1 GB RAM VM gives say for example 1000TPS  where as deploying in Kubernetes takes 3 cores and 4GB RAM to give the same 1000TPS. Not sure where is the huge difference coming from.

Comment: If your application is running on a machine with other pods it could very well be getting CPU throttled which could explain the performance issues you're seeing. I suggest watching this video by Bruno Borges, https://youtu.be/wApqCjHWF8Q?t=15

Comment: Thanks,
I have started considering the springboot-optimized docker base images.will keep updating here as i progress.